# Using lapply to make boxplots of a variable list

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

I want this type of boxplot for several y-variables in my dataset: [normal boxplot for all irises with Species as x-value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgWSC.png). Since I have multiple y variables to plot, I tried to use lapply like this:

```
varlist <- c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width')

plot <- function (varlist) {
  require(ggplot2)
  ggplot(data = iris, aes(x=Species, y=varlist))+
    geom_boxplot() 
}

lapply(varlist, FUN = plot)
```

I got this plot:
[with only one iris per plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1mDk.png)

How can I get normal boxplots using a type of loop (because of several y-values), and where all irises grouped by the x-variable are included in the boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, `aes()` does not handle string inputs; you need `aes_string()`. I expect (but have not tested) that your function will work if you change you `ggplot()` call to `ggplot(data = iris, mapping = aes_string(x = 'Species', y = varlist))`.

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr` you could do:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")


varlist <- c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width')

customPlot <- function(varName) {

iris %>% 
group_by_("Species") %>% 
select_("Species",varName) %>% 
ggplot(aes_string("Species",varName)) + geom_boxplot()

}
lapply(varlist,customPlot)
```

**Plots:**

[image]

[image]

Also note that `plot` is a base function for general plotting.It is not safe to overwrite base functions with user defined functions as it could lead to unexpected results later.